# What are the proper security measures involved with opening a port with Python?

Tags: python, security, sockets, ports

Consider a very basic python socket which opens up a port to the internet on the host computer and listens for incoming messages, which are displayed in a terminal.

Keeping a port wide open like this is considered fairly vulnerable, correct? What security features should I implement? Should incoming data be sanitized? What's the best way of going about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you've written so far?  What are you passing?  Never trust data you don't sanitize.  Encrypt anything sensitive.  Having a listening port isn't a flaw on its own, but you need to provide more context for a meaningful answer.

Comment: wow some people just don't have a clue.

Answer (score 6):

Why would this be vulnerable? Your program accepts connections from arbitrary people (potentially on the whole Internet), and lets them display arbitrary bytes to your terminal. There is only one attack vector here: your terminal itself. If your terminal has a bug that (for example) *executes* bytes instead of *printing* them, then the system could be compromised because of this setup.

However, that is unlikely -- in fact, one common technique for verifying that programs aren't totally broken is to pass arbitrary data into them and see if/how they explode. This is called [fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing), and if there was such a bug in your terminal when it was fuzz tested, the fuzz test would produce really interesting explosions, rather than just terminal garbage.

Just because something is accessible to the Internet on a port doesn't mean there's a vulnerability. You need an actual exploitable flaw, and in this case, there probably isn't one. (Although one never knows.)

Comment: Indeed, unless your Python script [`exec()`s the code sent over the wire](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Client-side_PHP.aspx), you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to secure? Using Python to listen on a socket isn't going to directly expose you to a vuln unless the Python interpreter has an unknown vuln.

Handling incoming messages is a different matter.

If you're writing to a terminal, does that mean the incoming data is expected to be in a specific format? How are you parsing incoming data? What happens if someone cats /dev/random into your port and leaves the connection open for a nice, long time?

Does the order or content of messages matter?

And so on. There aren't many specifics of the scenario to comment on, so the recommendations will be equally vague. As a start, take a look at OWASP [secure coding principles](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Secure_Coding_Principles) for general concepts (they're applicable even if you're not dealing with HTTP or HTML).

Comment: but the interpreter could be executing a vulnerable program...

Comment: yeah, that's the distinction I was going for in terms of "handling incoming messages". The original post was too vague on the code path between data arrives on a socket and shows up in a terminal.